# C++ convert a float array to float* (pointer)

Tags: c++, floating

I wonder how to convert a float array to a float* 
I have this situation :

```
float* floatTab = {12f, 0.5f, 3f};
```

It gives me an error here. but if I write it like this `float floatTab[3] = {12f, 0.5f, 3f};`it compiles alright.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Use the code that "compiles alright".

Comment: I have a framework that uses a float* i can't pass a float[] so i can't use the code that compiles

Comment: floatTab will *decay* to a float* if used as a function parameter, but use the code that "complile [sic] alright" to create the array.

Comment: You *can* pass a `float[]`. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: I have this error when trying to compile the above code excess elements in scalar initializer

Comment: @DrissBounouar A pointer is not an array.  That is the simple explanation for the error.  That initialization is for arrays, not a pointer.  A pointer is a single, integral value, not a set of values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works OK:

`float floatTab[3] = {12f, 0.5f, 3f};
float* ptr = floatTab;`

Comment: Thanks. I was doing some extra changes to the same above code trying to give a reference instead of doing as simple as this.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer STL containers instead of C arrays (or others RAII-conform classes):

```
const std::array<float, 3> array = { 1.f, 2.f, 3.f };
float *ptr = &array[0];
```

Don't forget to include `<array>` and `<initializer_list>` to compile this code.